# Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, ssis, etl

I created SSIS package:

- this package is running powershell file
- this powershell file is running SQL file

I tried to run this SSIS package with two ways :

1. Use .bat file which executes the SSIS package >> This way is running successfully.
2. Use powershell  file which executes the SSIS package >> This way is failing with the following Error

**Error Message:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=15.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Could I get help regarding this issue ??

I tried re-install SSMS-Setup-ENU but still have the same issue.

Comment: This may have something to do with `bitness`, so if running the 32-bit or 64-bit versions of the assemblies. Although this article is not for your version, have a look [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35832.sql-server-troubleshooting-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser.aspx) and  [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956178/error-message-when-you-run-a-32-bit-version-of-sql-server-2008-on-an-i)

Comment: What version of SQL Server you have?

Comment: What are the commands you are using? Are you running both commands in the same environment (machine)?

Answer (score 0):

After tried several feature packs and read a few discussion threads.
I found jendev provided [a repo](https://github.com/Jandev/SmoSample) in [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/sqltoolsservice/issues/783) which you can clone and get the dll after compile.

If you don't have Visual Studio then take [my fork](https://github.com/iamshiao/SmoSample) which has included the exact dll already.

Answer (score 0):

This issue fixed by using
Import-Module Sqlps -DisableNameChecking;
before executing sql script from ps file

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell to run DTEXEC.exe, then capture ERRORLEVEL using $LASTEXITCODE.

```
& DTEXEC.exe /?
$return = $LASTEXITCODE
if ($return) { throw "LASTEXITCODE = $LASTEXITCODE" }
```